# Filter returning wrong results

Tags: php, laravel, filter

... Either that or I'm not using / understanding it correctly. Take a look at my test snippet:

```
$subscriptions = auth()->user()->subscriptions()->get();

$id = '40';

$test = $subscriptions->filter(function ($subscription) use ($id) {
    return $subscription->where('description_id', $id);
});

dd($test);
```

Currently there is one `Subscription` in the database, with a `description_id` of 20. When running the above test snippet, I still get the one result returned that has a `description_id` of 20. So, this is not an expected result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where()` is used to filter a collection, but you're giving it a single subscription at a time when you use `filter()`. And since `where()` is also a method on an Eloquent model, what you're saying is essentially

> Go through all subscriptions. For each one, start creating a SQL query. Unless that evaluates to false, keep the subscription in the list of all subscriptions.

Instead, what you mean to do is pretty close but not quite the same:

```
$test = $subscriptions->filter(function ($subscription) use ($id) {
    return $subscription->description_id == $id;
});
```

Depending on what you want to do in practice, there may be other, more suitable methods as well. For instance, if you only want the first result since you only have a single id, then you can just replace `filter` above with `first`, and get the first matching subscription back rather than a collection of one subscription.

Comment: Thanks, now I at least understand it, couldn't wrap my head around it, but it makes total sense. I AM indeed filtering through a bunch of subscriptions, and I only want to continue with the ones that match the given `description_id`, so your example will work perfectly, thanks! Will accept this answer as soon as I can